# Call a function in a child component based on an input from user in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app, there is a parent component (pc) and 4 child components (cc1,cc2,cc3,cc4). Consider the scenario where a user enters a number between 1-4 in an input text for example, and I wish to call a function in the corresponding component.

If I wanted to call the function from child component 2, let's say, I could do it by using @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('cc2') child;
```

and then calling the function by :

```
 this.child.somefunc();
```

However, I can not do something like

```
@ViewChild('cc'+ ValuefromUser)
```

in an onClick event for example to get a reference to the desired component. Do you have any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be queried with `ViewChild` to different variables:

```
@ViewChild('cc1') child1;
@ViewChild('cc2') child2;
...
```

In this case template element can be referred either by template variable name (e.g. `cc1` string) or by component class (e.g. `Child1Component`).

Or they can be queried with `ViewChildren` to same variable:

```
@ViewChildren('cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4') children;
```

In this case template elements can be referred only by template variable name. It will be harder to differentiate between them, because `children` contains instances of component classes, and they should be checked against a map of classes in order to filter the ones with desired identifier with `QueryList` `filter` or `find`:

```
const childrenMap = { 1: Child1Component1, 2: ... };

...

const filteredChildren = children.filter(child => {
  if (childrenMap[valuefromUser])
    return filteredChild instanceof childrenMap[valuefromUser]);
});
```

Comment: I am still not sure how to use \@ViewChild for my case. As you suggested I created 4 references to cc1 ... cc4 using \@ViewChild. But how can I access to child+valuefromUser when a click is pressed?

Comment: As in any JS case, it's `this['cc' + valuefromUser]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten this is possible!